# Wordpress query custom date field ordered by day

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

I hava a custom post type called "employees". In this I have a custom date field called "birthday".

Now I need to query a list of all birhdays of the current month, ordered by day of the date field (birthday) and not by year.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
$current_month = date('m'); // get current month
$filter_month = $current_month; // show current month only
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'employees',
    'meta_key'=>'birthday',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'=>'meta_value', 
    'order'=>'DESC', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'birthday',
            'value'   => $current_month,
            'compare' => 'REGEXP',
            'value'   => '[0-9]{4}' . $filter_month . '[0-9]{2}',
        ),
    ),

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );if ( $query ->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

With this I get a list like:

- 05.03.2002 - Person A
- 11.03.1998 - Person B
- 24.03.1995 - Person C
- 03.03.1970 - Person D

My goal is a list, odered by day, not year, like:

- 03.03.1970 - Person D
- 05.03.2002 - Person A
- 11.03.1998 - Person B
- 24.03.1995 - Person C

Any hints for me?
Thank you

Comment: How is the data stored in the birthday field?  Standard ACF ('Ymd') format?

Comment: Yes. I have checked my DB and the dates are in Ymd like 20200417. On blog edit, I set the value as d.m.Y for in- and output, but this shpild not change the standard ACF-DB-entry.

Comment: I have one other question. Are you using the ACF datepicker for the data entry screen? (Post edit).  What is the input format of each date?

Comment: Ho Howard. Yes, I am using ACF datepicker and my input format is "d.m.Y" for both, the display formst and the return format.

Comment: OK, I have an idea.  Will post something later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a solution to your problem.  I thought it might be easier to add additional meta fields, "`birthday_month`" and "`birthday_day`" - so if you add those on `post_save` hook, you dont' have to do any additional data entry.

```php
add_action('save_post', 'he_add_birthday_details', 10, 1);
function he_add_birthday_details($postid){
// Check if birthday is set 
if (!empty(get_post_meta($postid, 'birthday', true))) {
    // if it is set - get it
    $birthday = get_post_meta($postid, 'birthday', true);
    // parse the date into components
    $month = date('m' , strtotime($birthday));
    $day = date('d', strtotime($birthday));
    // Save new postmeta fields
    update_post_meta($postid, 'birthday_month', $month);
    update_post_meta($postid, 'birthday_day', $day);
}
```

Then you can do your loop with the new fields.

```php
 $current_month = date('m'); // get current month
 $filter_month = $current_month; // show current month only
 $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'employees',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key'     => 'birthday_month',
        'value'   => $current_month
     ),
     'date_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'birthday_day',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )   
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date_clause',
    'order' => 'ASC'
 );

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much für your help! This solution works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
 $current_month = date('m'); // get current month
 $filter_month = $current_month; // show current month only
 $args = array(
       'post_type'  => 'employees',
       'meta_key'=>'birthday',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'orderby' => array(
               'birthday' => 'DESC',
               'meta_value'=> 'DESC',
        ),
    'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key'     => 'birthday',
        'value'   => $current_month,
        'compare' => 'REGEXP',
        'value'   => '[0-9]{4}' . $filter_month . '[0-9]{2}',
     ),
  ),
 );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );if ( $query ->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi
Thank you, but this ist going to order the whole date in key "birthday". 
I would like to order only by day, not year.